# Slow simple mysql query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-slow-query-log

I have a problem with the speed of query. Simple mysql query, but when I have a lot of records (currently > 1 000 000), the performance is really slow. Question is similar to this one, but can't find solution. Explain says that MySQL is using: Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort. Has anyone any suggestions to speed it up? Slow query:

```
select 
    `books`.`id`
from `books`
join `books_data` on `books_data`.`book_id` = `books`.`id`
where 
    `books`.`is_status` = 'active'
order by `books_data`.`date_add` DESC
limit 0, 10
```

Result:

```
10 rows (0.525 s)
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
1   SIMPLE  books   NULL    ref PRIMARY,is_status,is_status_read_num,is_status_reviews_count,is_status_year_read_num,is_status_poster_name  is_status   1   const   112342  100.00  Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  books_data  NULL    ref book_id,book_id_date_add    book_id 4   mon.books.id    1   100.00  NULL
```

My tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `books` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_original` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `annotation` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
  `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `year_original` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `year_publishing` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `poster` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `read_num` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `reviews_count` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `views_count` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `rating` decimal(4,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0',
  `is_status` enum('new','active','duplicate','deleted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'new',
  `deleted_reason` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `duplicate_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `new_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `is_status` (`is_status`),
  KEY `read_num` (`read_num`),
  KEY `reviews_count` (`reviews_count`),
  KEY `views_count` (`views_count`),
  KEY `is_status_read_num` (`is_status`,`read_num`),
  KEY `is_status_reviews_count` (`is_status`,`reviews_count`),
  KEY `year_original` (`year_original`),
  KEY `year` (`year`),
  KEY `is_status_year_read_num` (`is_status`,`year`,`read_num`),
  KEY `year_publishing` (`year_publishing`),
  KEY `new_id` (`new_id`),
  KEY `is_status_poster_name` (`is_status`,`poster`,`name`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
CREATE TABLE `books_data` (
  `book_id` int NOT NULL,
  `date_add` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `file_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `book_id` (`book_id`),
  KEY `file_id` (`file_id`),
  KEY `date_add` (`date_add`),
  KEY `book_id_date_add` (`book_id`,`date_add`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Comment: Half a second to sort a megarow dataset and return a fraction of it is not absurdly slow, for what it's worth.  Can you change your query to say something like `ON books_data.book_id = books.id AND books_data.date_add >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH` to filter out older items, without damaging your business logic?

Comment: @O.Jones - I assume you are also removing `status`, or at least avoiding the `JOIN`?

Comment: Didn't intend remove any columns in my comment. Just meant to restrict the date range hoping it would speed the query along.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this combination:

- Filter on one table (see `WHERE`)
- Sort by another table (see `ORDER BY`)
- `LIMIT`

**Formulation 1**

The query will be executed this way:

1. A scan of the index BTree for `bools.is_status` to do the filtering.  Note: The cardinality of `status` probably does not warrant using an index.
2. For each of those rows, find the matching row in `books_data`.
3. Sort the results to achieve `ORDER BY ...`
4. Deliver the first `LIMIT 10` rows.

Cost:

- Partial scan of the index `books.is_status`
- Reach into the index `books_data.book_id` that many times.
- Reach into the table `books_data` that many times.
- Sort
- Deliver 10.

**Formulation 2**

You should Drop KEY `book_id` (`book_id`) since it is in the way of using the better ("covering") `book_id_date_add`.  This eliminates the third bullet item.

**Formulation 3**

If you could eliminate the test on `status` (step 1), then `INDEX(date_add)` could be used, and the execution would be:

1. Using `INDEX(date_add)`, find the last 10 items.
2. Reach (10 times only) into `books` for `books.id`.

Cost:

- 10 rows from books_data.date_add
- 10 rows from books

The second bullet could be circumvented by delivering `books_data.book_id` instead of `books.id`.

However, the second bullet has a side effect that may not be needed -- It verifies that there is an entry in `books` for the desired `books_data.book_id`

**Formulation 4**

Consider this rewrite:

```
SELECT bd.book_id
    FROM books_book_data AS bd
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM books WHERE id = bd.book_id );
```

That eliminates the caveat mentioned in Formulation 3.

The Cost *may* be:

- Scan at least 10 rows of `INDEX(book_id, date_add)`
- For each, to a single probe to verify that `status = 'active'`.  (10+ more rows)

This formulation 4

- honors the apparent intent
- will stop reasonably fast if not to many are not 'active'.

**Notes**

- I have been assuming: 1 (books) :: many (books_data)
- If the tables are 1::1, combine them; all this discussion goes away.
- Every table should have a `PRIMARY KEY`.  If there is no 'natural' PK, use an `AUTO_INCREMENT.  If the combination` (book_id, file_id)` is unique, then it would be a likely PK.
- Whenever you have both `INDEX(a)` and `INDEX(a,b)`, drop the former; its existence can lead to a less optimal execution plan.